# Angular Google Maps cluster disappears on zooming in

Tags: angularjs, google-maps

I'm using angular-google-maps 2.3.2, I have clusters somewhat working, the cluster icon with the correct number is showing, and if I zoom out the markers combine correctly, but I can't zoom in to get the individual markers, not sure what I'm missing.

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center='vm.map.center' zoom='vm.map.zoom'>
        <div>
            <ui-gmap-markers fit="true" models="vm.markers" doCluster="true" coords="'self'"
                              clusterOptions="{ imagePath: 'images/m' }"
                              events="vm.map.markers.markersEvents" options="'self'" modelsbyref="false">
                <ui-gmap-windows templateUrl="'template'"
                                 templateParameter="'info'"
                                 show="'showWindow'"
                                 closeClick="'closeClick'"></ui-gmap-windows>
            </ui-gmap-markers>
        </div>
    </ui-gmap-google-map>
```